# How to make sure that $http requests are executed in sequence inside loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, angular-promise

I'm in need to make ajax chain request.

```
function _GetCustomerDetails() {
  //Customer
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataService.get(sData, 'Customer').then(function(data) {
      if (data.entity === "Customer" && data.rows != undefined && data.rows.length > 0) {
        var len = data.rows.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (data.rows[i] != undefined) {
            //load related entity
            dataService.get(data.CustomerId, 'CustomerRelatedEntity').then(function(data) {
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

However, the customer data is loading fine but the nested related entity is not loading correct. It fills all the data with the last one.(i.e, **the customer at index =4**)

This is how my data service looks like.

```
 angular
  .module('app')
  .service('dataService', dataService);

dataService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

function dataService($http, $q) {
  var service = {
    get: _get,

  }
  return service;

  function _get(data, tableName) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var url = "API_Url";
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,

      })
      .then(success)
      .catch(exception);

    function success(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    function exception(ex) {
      deferred.reject(response);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Could you please format & tidy up your codes. Thanks.

Comment: @Kgn-web How are you passing the index to the service. I dont see any index at all? data.customerId, doesnt make sense. It would have if it's something like data.rows[i].customerId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do it by using a generator like [tj/co](https://github.com/tj/co). In that way your loop steps will be forwarded once your promise has been recived. This example will work fine if `data.rows` is an `array`.

```
function _GetCustomerDetails() {
  dataService.get(sData, 'Customer').then(function(data) {
    if (data.entity === "Customer" && data.rows != undefined && data.rows.length > 0) {
      co(function*() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
          let data = yield new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             dataService.get(data.rows[i].CustomerId, 'CustomerRelatedEntity').then(function (result) {
                resolve(result);
             });;
          });
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Reproduce your problem

Take a look at this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd5gpn97/)** which reproduces your problem. As you can see, the loop finished before all requests respond / finished.

#### Fix your problem

Take a look at this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8d8stut/)** which is one way to fix your problem and sync your loop. As you can see, the loop waits for all request to finish before starting the next loop sequence.

Comment: `data.rows` is an array but the issue is while loading the related entity & I am getting the related entity of the last one.(i=4)

Please check the updated post, I have added a for loop on the top of the controller.

Comment: Yes m8, I did understand your problem and this answer solves it. Your loop does not wait for an HTTP-Request to finish because its ASYNC. In that way you fire all your HTTP-Request in a loop and you do not know which HTTP-Request finished at first or last. That means e.g. that your  HTTP-Request you fired at the last loop could be the first which is responding.

Comment: Okay.Let me check with my case. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kgn-web Does it work for you?

Comment: `(function * (item) ` why *?? Is it typo mistake or intentional `yield  dataService.get(sData, 'CustomerRelatedEntity').then(function (data) {
                                    })`

Comment: This is throwing error

Comment: @Kgn-web `function * ()` is based on https://github.com/tj/co please include this package and read the documentation.

Comment: @Kgn-web I will add a working example jsfiddle in the next hours.

Comment: sure,it would be really kind of you

Comment: https://codepaste.net/nnxb67, Please check this link this is what exactly I need to do, I know there are better ways to do it but there is some business  restrictions that forces me to do in this way only

Comment: @Kgn-web check my update. Your codepast was not found btw. I finally added a working example and updated the answer code

Comment: Thanks mate :) I am marking your post accepted.

Comment: Please upvote my post if you think its worth